# Django update view with user selected filter, possible be ajax?

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

I am a beginner and still learning how to update view based on user input.

When a user selects speciality, city, last_name I would like the output to sort by that field.

I am trying to do this without reloading but not sure if this possible.
I would be happy in the short term just to get functionality to work.

> error 500: TypeError at /md/
>     expected string or bytes-like object

js

```
$(function(){
 $(".options").click(function() {

        var filterby;
        filterby = $(this).attr("dvalue");
        console.log('options  start', filterby);
        $.ajax({
            url : "/md/",
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                "filterby" : filterby,
                "csrfmiddlewaretoken" : $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
            },
            success: console.log("success"),
            dataType: "html",
            error: function(xhr, errmsg, err){
                console.log(xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.responseText);
            }
    });
 });
});
```

views.py

```
def physicians(request):
    user = User;
    liked = False;
    args = {}
    filterby ='speciality'
    if request.method == 'POST':
       filterby = request.POST.get('filterby', None)
       print("filterby", filterby)

    args.update(csrf(request))
    physicians = Physician.objects.all().order_by(filterby)

    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    paginator = Paginator(physicians, 10)
    try:
        physicians = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        physicians = paginator.page(1)
   except EmptyPage:
        physicians = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

   physicians_liked = 
    Voter.objects.filter(user=request.user).values_list('physician', flat=True)


    args['physicians'] = physicians
    args['physicians_liked'] = physicians_liked    
    return render(request, 'physicians.html',  args )
```

html code

```
<h3> Find You Favorite Doctors </h3>
<table class="table">
<thead>
<tr>
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <p>Sort By: </p>
        </div>    
        <div class="btn-group col-md-10 pull-left align-center" data-
        toggle="buttons">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <label class="options btn btn-custom active" 
                 dvalue="speciality" >
                  <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" 
                      value="speciality" checked> Speciality
                </label>
                <label class="options btn btn-custom" dvalue="last_name">
                  <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" 
           value="last_name"> Last Name
                </label>
                <label class="options btn btn-custom" dvalue="city">
                  <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" 
              value="city"> City
                </label>
              </div>
        </div>
</tr>    
<tr></tr>
<tr>
```

Comment: add absolute url in ajax call.

Comment: Make the ajax request type a `GET` since you're not mutating the resource

Answer (score 0):

Passing `None` or an empty string as fieldname to queryset `order_by` method leads to a `TypeError`.

> Method signature for **order_by**:
>
> ```
>     def order_by(self, *fieldnames)
> ```
>
> Usage: queryset.order_by('field1', '-field2')
> # sorts queryset by field1 in ascending order and field2 in descending order.

A default field name to sort with must be passed.

First, correct typo in <s>filterby = $(this).attr("dvalue");</s> by changing to:

```
filterby = $(this).attr("value");
```

Then make sure that there is always a default field to sort with.

```
filterby = request.POST.get('filterby', 'first_name')
```

Or only ever order if a filter is passed.

```
physicians = (
    Physician.objects.all() 
    if filter_by in (None, '') 
    else Physician.objects.all().order_by(filterby)
)
```

Comment: Thanks. No error now but functionality not working e.g., screen is not updating. Can Ajax cause a page refresh or past the new query set to my template and trigger an changes to screen?

Comment: Since your service returns HTML, you can use jQuery to select the result part of the markup in the returned HTML and replace it with the result part on the current rendered markup.

Comment: Ok that you are saying do a for loop and relist the physicians in the <li> in Javascript

Comment: Something like that. However doing a for loop is expensive. Replacing outdated list part in the dom with the list in result will be more efficient.